# AngularJs filter not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The view in my html is not getting filtered on selecting any li element.

But when I console the filter functions the output generated is correct.Also how to clear the filter so it is reusable again.I'm getting a blank page on clicking open or close select elements.Can anyone help me with this.
I have used two filters in a controller inside the functions like this-

indexController Functions-

```
this.UserTickets = ()=> {
    //code to get the tickets
}

this.openTickets = () => {
    index.filteredTickets = $filter('filter')(index.tickets, { status: "open" } );
    console.log(index.filteredTickets);
};

//filter closed tickets
this.closeTickets =  () => {
    index.filteredTickets = $filter('filter')(index.tickets, { status: "close" } );
    console.log(index.filteredTickets);
};

this.clearFilter = () => {
    //clear the filter
};
```

HTML-

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a ng-click="indexCtrl.clearfilter()">None</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="indexCtrl.openTickets()">Open</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="indexCtrl.closeTickets()">Close</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-repeat="ticket in indexCtrl.tickets | filter:tickets |filter:indexCtrl.filteredTickets">
    <div class="ticket-no">
        <h4>Ticket No:<span>{{ticket}}</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="ticket-title">
        <a ng-href="/ticketView/{{ticket.ticketid}}"><h3>{{ticket.title}}</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ticket-info">
        <p class="pull-left">{{ticket.username}} On {{ticket.created | date:"MMM d, y h:mm a"}}</p>
        <p class="pull-right">Status:<span>{{ticket.status}}</span></p>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing both angular filter options. I would recommend the javascript filters, `index.filteredTickets=$filter('filter')(index.tickets,{status:"open"});` rather than the html template syntax, `ng-repeat="ticket in indexCtrl.tickets | filter:tickets..."`. The key difference between these methods is how often they are run. The html template syntax filters are run on every digest cycle, the javascript filters are only run when the method is called, in your case, on each button click. For small apps or when the lists are small, this difference won't be noticeable, but if your app grows in size, the constant filtering on each digest cycle can cause page lag.

The filters in the controller are my preferred way of handling this, so I will show you how to clean up your code for these to work. You are almost there, just a few small changes are needed.

In your html, you can remove the inline filters in the `ng-repeat`, these aren't needed, and change the array to be your filter list, `index.filteredTickets`.

**.html**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a ng-click="indexCtrl.clearfilter()">None</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="indexCtrl.openTickets()">Open</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="indexCtrl.closeTickets()">Close</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-repeat="ticket in indexCtrl.filteredTickets">
    <div class="ticket-no">
        <h4>Ticket No:<span>{{ticket}}</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="ticket-title">
        <a ng-href="/ticketView/{{ticket.ticketid}}"><h3>{{ticket.title}}</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ticket-info">
        <p class="pull-left">{{ticket.username}} On {{ticket.created | date:"MMM d, y h:mm a"}}</p>
        <p class="pull-right">Status:<span>{{ticket.status}}</span></p>

    </div>
    <hr class="hr">
</div>
```

For the javascript, you need to make sure the `filteredTickets` are accessible in the html. I'm not sure if `index == this`, if not, you may need to attach the filtered tickets to the scope. The one other change needed is to set the `filteredTickets` to your original list if the `none` button is pressed. You will also want to call `clearFilter` after you load the list, otherwise `index.filteredList` will be undefined/null.

**.js**

```
this.UserTickets = () => {
    //code to get the tickets
    ....
    //after getting list, call clear filter
    this.clearFilter();
}

this.openTickets = () => {
    index.filteredTickets = $filter('filter')(index.tickets, { status: "open" } );
    console.log(index.filteredTickets);
};

//filter closed tickets
this.closeTickets = () => {
    index.filteredTickets = $filter('filter')(index.tickets, { status: "close" } );
    console.log(index.filteredTickets);
};

this.clearFilter = () => {
    //clear the filter
    index.filteredTickets = index.tickets;
};
```

Comment: Thank You so much.Works like a charm:)